# WCF connections are aborted incorrectly / existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: .net, wcf, timeout, connection

I have a Windows application that uses WCF service. It has some WCF service calls, and `ClientBase.Close()` method is always called afterwards. When I close the application, I do not get any errors in it in VS2010. I've turned on all exceptions in the debugger and attached my compiler to everything I could. I am closing all connections, and no WCF service calls are running asynchronously when I am closing my app.

But I do get an exception on the WCF service!

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was (some big number goes here).

The error code is `10054`

And the inner exception is:

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

But how could this happen to my code?

What can I do to find the reason of this erroneous behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Increase the `ChannelInitializationTimeout`

> Maximum time to wait for a connection to send the preamble during the
>   initial read. This data is received before authentication occurs.

Default value is 5 sec. This is cause "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." exception.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on WCF tracing on the server, view the results with WCF trace viewer, make sure app pool has rights to directory with service ...

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
          switchValue="Verbose" 
          propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="traceListener" 
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
           initializeData="Events.evt"  />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<trace autoflush="true"/>
```